# Four prime numbers

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $p,q,r$ and $s$ be prime numbers such that $p<q<r<s$ and $p^s-r^q=3$ .
I would like to detect $p,q,r$ and $s$.
Because $q,r$ and $s$ are odd number, I get $p=2$. By Felmat’s little theorem, $2^s ≡ 2 $mod $s$ and $r^{s-1} ≡ 1$ mod $s$.So, I get that $s-1$ can be devided by $2q$. However I can not detect...( I think only $(p,q,r,s)=(2,3,5,7)$.) Please give me hints!

Comment: The the solution at [art of problem solving](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h2427594p20017612). The only answer is indeed $(p,q,r,s)=(2,3,5,7)$.

Comment: Usually such equations are extremely difficult to solve. If we omit the requirement that $p,q,r,s$ are primes this leads to the unsolved Pillai conjecture (an extension of the now proven Catalan conjecture where the difference is $1$)